# How do I prove that if $A, B \in S$ and $A \subset B$ then $B \setminus A \in S$ in probability theory?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, solution-verification

My proof is as follow (S is the event space in the probability space of an experiment):

If $A \subset B \in S$ then $A^c \cap B \in S$ so this means that $A^c\cap B$ contains B but not A. This implies that $B \setminus A \in S$

I'm not sure if this prove is correct and if the rigor is strong enough.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need that $A\subseteq B$. As you mentioned, it is sufficient to see that
$$B\backslash A=B\cap A^\complement$$
and to recall that the sigma-algebra $S$ is closed under taking complements and intersections.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C$ be the set of elementary events (the largest element of the sigma algebra $S$). As with each set in $S$ also its complement is in $S$, we have $C\setminus B\in S$. As with any two sets, also its union is in $S$, we have

$$B\setminus A = (A\cup (C\setminus B))^c \in S.$$

[edit: the complement $A^c$ of any set $A$ is the same as $C\setminus A$ in the example]